# How to add source code snippets into _data yaml in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to create code snippets as examples for my project website created in Jekyll.

I have yaml that look like this:

```yaml
-
  description: "Scheme hygienic macro that creates assoc list, with macroexpand."
  code: >
     (define-syntax alist
       (syntax-rules ()
          ((_) ())
          ((_ x y z ...)
           (cons (cons x y) (alist z ...)))))

     (print (alist "foo" 10 "bar" 20 "baz" 30))
     ;; ==> ((foo . 10) (bar . 20) (baz . 30))
     (macroexpand (alist "foo" 10 "bar" 20))
     ;; ==> (#:cons (#:cons "foo" 10)
                    (#:cons (#:cons "bar" 20)
                            ()))
```

the problem is that lines that are exactly the same indent as first line are concatenated into single line. I want this to be exactly like in yaml in my pre tag. If I indent every line that be one more space I get extra space in pre tag when I'm adding the snippet.

Is there any way to make it insert exactly the code I have in yaml file? how to properly indent in yaml to not have then spaces before each line and have each line in it's own line in output html?

I was trying to add quotes around the string but they are present in output and I was not able to removed them in Liquid.

I've tried this:

```
  {% for example in site.data.examples %}
  {% assign code = example.code | split: '^"|"$' %}
  <li>
    <div class="example">
      <pre>{{ code[1] }}</pre>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      {{ example.description }}
    </div>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

but split don't accept regular expressions. I've also tried:

```
{% assign len = example.code.length  %}
{% assign code = example.code | slice: 1,len-2  %}
```

but it only prints first parenthesis.
**EDIT:**

I've solved issue with removing quotes but that was dead end, I still got spaces before each line.

This is a way to remove quotes from string in Jekyll:

```
{% assign code = example.code | remove_first: '"' | rstrip | append: "__" | remove: '"__'  %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is simpler than I though. All that is required is block in Yaml (ref: https://idratherbewriting.com/documentation-theme-jekyll/mydoc_yaml_tutorial.html)

```yaml
-
  description: "Scheme hygienic macro that creates assoc list, with macroexpand."
  code: |
     (define-syntax alist
       (syntax-rules ()
          ((_) ())
          ((_ x y z ...)
           (cons (cons x y) (alist z ...)))))

     (print (alist "foo" 10 "bar" 20 "baz" 30))
     ;; ==> ((foo . 10) (bar . 20) (baz . 30))
     (macroexpand (alist "foo" 10 "bar" 20))
     ;; ==> (#:cons (#:cons "foo" 10)
                    (#:cons (#:cons "bar" 20)
                            ()))
```

And you can use normal variable:

```
  {% for example in site.data.examples %}
  <li>
    <div class="example">
      <pre>{{ example.code }}</pre>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      {{ example.description }}
    </div>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

**If above don't work for you, here is old version of the answer:**

Liquid is very limited but I was able to create this hack:

```
  {% for example in site.data.examples %}
  {% assign code = example.code | remove_first: '"' | rstrip | append: "__" | remove: '"__'  | newline_to_br | split: "<br />" %}
  <li>
    <div class="example">
      <pre>{% for line in code %}{{ line | remove_first: " " }}{% endfor %}</pre>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      {{ example.description }}
    </div>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

and for reference this is my examples.yaml

```yaml
-
  description: "Scheme hygienic macro that creates assoc list, with macroexpand."
  code: >
    " (define-syntax alist
       (syntax-rules ()
          ((_) ())
          ((_ x y z ...)
           (cons (cons x y) (alist z ...)))))

     (print (alist "foo" 10 "bar" 20 "baz" 30))
     ;; ==> ((foo . 10) (bar . 20) (baz . 30))
     (macroexpand (alist "foo" 10 "bar" 20))
     ;; ==> (#:cons (#:cons "foo" 10)
                    (#:cons (#:cons "bar" 20)
                            ()))"
```